# let background process write to stdout of foreground process

Tags: bash, stdout

I have an nginx docker container, which needs to run an extra node server in the background (I'm not able to use two containers/docker compose).

I can add a script into `/docker-entrypoint.d/` and nginx will run that script when it's starting up.

How can I run a process in background, but let the stdout of that background process just pipe directly into my parent processes stdout? i.e. I want all the logs from both processes to just go to stdout immediately, this way it's easy to trace along what's happening between the two

Answer (score 1):

Basically just run this in your shell script:

```bash
bg-process &
```

You may want to wrap your process in some sort of process management tool like pm2, which will intelligently restart your process if it suddenly dies:

```bash
./node_modules/.bin/pm2-runtime start ./pm2.json
```